# Get only HTML <head> Element with a Script or Tool

Tags: python, html, curl, scripting, wget

I am trying to get large amount of status information, which are encoded in websites, mainly inside the "< head >< /head >" element.

I know I can use `wget` or `curl` or python to get the whole page. But I don't want to put too much unnecessary stress to the servers (the pages themself are rather large/complicated).

**Is there any method of getting only the head-element?**

I assume there is something proxy servers do besides checking for html headers.

Jusk for clarification: I don't search for html-headers, only for html-`<head>`.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to load only the data between the `<head>` tags because the server would have to parse the requested page before sending it.

A possible solution would read a few bytes until a `</head>` tag is found.

The following reads `n` bytes from the source and checks if the string `</head>` is included. If so, the bytes are converted to `string` and trimmed such that the result contains the tags `<head>` and `</head>` as well as the data between them. Otherwise it continues to read `n` bytes until `</head>` is found.

```
import urllib.request


def get_head_tag_data(url, n=512):
    """Read n bytes form source until '</head> is included. Trim result to
       '<head> ... </head>' and return it as string."""

    # open resource
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as site:
        # read n bytes until `buff` includes "</head>"
        data = b''
        i = 1
        while True:
            buff = site.read(n)
            data += buff
            if b'</head>' in buff:
                break
            elif buff == b'':
                raise AttributeError('Not head-tag found.')
            i += 1

    print('{} bytes read'.format(n*i))

    # cast to string
    data = str(data)

    # detect tag position
    start_tag = data.find('<head>')
    end_tag = data.find('</head>') + 7

    return data[start_tag:end_tag]


tag_data = get_head_tag_data('https://stackoverflow.com', n=256)
```

Note that this functions does not check for possible erros, for example if there is no `</head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this also downloads the whole page first.

Answer (score -3):

You can try BeautifulSoap. Here is an example **Python** script.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'change_wiht_your_desired_url' # www.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262523/get-only-html-head-element-with-a-script-or-tool 
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
soup.head
```

You can get different tags using the `soup` object. Read the full [docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup). I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

`print(soup.head)` outputs

```
<head>
<title>Memory Leak with import_array() for numpy Python3.5 - Stack Overflow</title>
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d" rel="shortcut icon"/>
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" rel="apple-touch-icon image_src"/>
<link href="/opensearch.xml" rel="search" title="Stack Overflow" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>
<meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
<meta content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200892/memory-leak-with-import-array-for-numpy-python3-5" property="og:url"/>
<meta content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" property="og:image"/>
<meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/>
<meta content="stackoverflow.com" name="twitter:domain"/>
<meta content="Memory Leak with import_array() for numpy Python3.5" itemprop="title name" name="twitter:title" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="Could someone suggest a fix for this problem?
When I use import_array(), Valgrind reports memory leak of 157528 bytes.
Here is the small piece of code to replicate the problem on Ubuntu16.04 and P..." itemprop="description" name="twitter:description" property="og:description"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=10cafd98c67a"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all-primary.css?v=44b77c3d4e1c" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/feeds/question/48200892" rel="alternate" title="Feed for question 'Memory Leak with import_array() for numpy Python3.5'" type="application/atom+xml"/>
<meta content="US" name="twitter:app:country"/>
<meta content="Stack Exchange iOS" name="twitter:app:name:iphone"/>
<meta content="871299723" name="twitter:app:id:iphone"/>
<meta content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200892/memory-leak-with-import-array-for-numpy-python3-5" name="twitter:app:url:iphone"/>
<meta content="Stack Exchange iOS" name="twitter:app:name:ipad"/>
<meta content="871299723" name="twitter:app:id:ipad"/>
<meta content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200892/memory-leak-with-import-array-for-numpy-python3-5" name="twitter:app:url:ipad"/>
<meta content="Stack Exchange Android" name="twitter:app:name:googleplay"/>
<meta content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200892/memory-leak-with-import-array-for-numpy-python3-5" name="twitter:app:url:googleplay"/>
<meta content="com.stackexchange.marvin" name="twitter:app:id:googleplay"/>
<script>

            StackExchange.ready(function () {

                    StackExchange.using("snippets", function () {
                        StackExchange.snippets.initSnippetRenderer();
                    });


                StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
                    StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
                });


                StackExchange.question.init({showAnswerHelp:true,totalCommentCount:2,shownCommentCount:2,highlightColor:'#F4A83D',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:48200892});

                styleCode();

                    StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion('1', '48200892');
                                                                    StackExchange.using("gps", function () { StackExchange.gps.trackOutboundClicks('#content', '.post-text'); });

            });
        </script>
<script>
        StackExchange.init({"locale":"en","serverTime":1516020520,"routeName":"Questions/Show","stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","networkMetaHostname":"meta.stackexchange.com","site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"recaptchaPublicKey":"6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc","recaptchaAudioLang":"en","enableNewTagCreationWarning":true,"insertSpaceAfterNameTabCompletion":false,"id":1,"childUrl":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com","enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true,"protocol":"https"},"user":{"fkey":"b01c42fe577b568489e86923067aebbd","tid":"5b158809-5378-6383-c1bd-bdf22c97f475","rep":0,"isAnonymous":true,"isAnonymousNetworkWide":true,"canSeeNewHeaderDesign":true},"events":{"postType":{"question":1},"postEditionSection":{"title":1,"body":2,"tags":3}},"story":{"minCompleteBodyLength":75,"likedTagsMaxLength":300,"dislikedTagsMaxLength":300},"jobPreferences":{"maxNumDeveloperRoles":2,"maxNumIndustries":4}}, {"site":{"allowImageUploads":true,"enableUserHovercards":true,"styleCode":true,"enableImgurHttps":true,"forceHttpsImages":true},"comments":{},"userProfile":{"openGraphAPIKey":"58740831ad23540e00c58987"},"tags":{},"accounts":{"currentPasswordRequiredForChangingStackIdPassword":true},"flags":{"allowRetractingFlags":true},"topBar":{"showNewFeatureNotice":true},"snippets":{"snippetsEnabled":true,"renderDomain":"stacksnippets.net"},"paths":{},"markdown":{"asteriskIntraWordEmphasis":true},"monitoring":{"clientTimingsAbsoluteTimeout":30000,"clientTimingsDebounceTimeout":1000}});
        StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.en.js":"653f3a9edf23","js/moderator.en.js":"22b640565fb8","js/full-anon.en.js":"448b407c0535","js/full.en.js":"b5454c77884f","js/wmd.en.js":"70a0e707c944","js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js":"d3b8fa7fdf74","js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.en.js":"","js/mobile.en.js":"8e20e188854d","js/help.en.js":"890f7bf1827b","js/tageditor.en.js":"68e773dc21b3","js/tageditornew.en.js":"c77ac7fa331f","js/inline-tag-editing.en.js":"681a5e3ebd00","js/revisions.en.js":"2faaeaae2529","js/review.en.js":"1cbc9c06f708","js/tagsuggestions.en.js":"b278f9a0b23b","js/post-validation.en.js":"d8d9b527c3ea","js/explore-qlist.en.js":"88f824a42b1a","js/events.en.js":"9c2e85f6190f","js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js":"a6f8e6251bbd","js/external-editor.en.js":"7a4d6f43f0bf","js/adops.en.js":"22a9bd59b1e9","js/external-editor.en.js":"7a4d6f43f0bf","js/snippet-javascript.en.js":"a3fb7827a7b4","js/snippet-javascript-codemirror.en.js":"72e55eacc0ed"});
        StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
             StackExchange.gps.init(true);
        });
    </script>
<noscript id="noscript-css"><style>body,.top-bar{margin-top:1.9em}</style></noscript>
</head>
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. He asked how to download only the data between `<head>` and `</head>`.

Comment: If you try above script it will show the all data between head tag. You can save it to a file.

Comment: @MaxPowers OP's question main part : Is there any method of getting only the head-element?  I answered it.

Comment: you are getting the whole page and parsing the head element out of it. OP wants to only get the head element.

Comment: Hmm. Okay if you found any better solution please let me know. @MaxPowers