# Get only HTML <head> from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web-scraping

> My question is similar to [this one about Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262523/get-only-html-head-element-with-a-script-or-tool), but, unlike it, mine is about Javascript.

## 1. The problem

1. I have a large list of Web Page URLs (about 10k) in plain text;
2. For each page@URL *(or for majority of)* I need to find some metadata and a **title**;
3. I want to **NOT LOAD** full pages, only load everything before `</head>` closing **tag**.

## 2. The questions

1. Is it possible to open a stream, load some bytes and, upon getting to the `</head>`, close stream and connection? If so, how?
2. Py's `urllib.request.Request.read()` has a "size" argument in number of bytes, but JS's `ReadableStreamDefaultReader.read()` does not. What should I use in JS then as an alternative?
3. Will this approach reduce network traffic, bandwidth usage, CPU and memory usage?

Comment: instead of using post or get , replace that with head and all done !

Comment: @YasserCHENIK will it give me a title?

Comment: oh you are looking for the head tag  !?

Comment: @YasserCHENIK yes, it is in the question

Comment: ye  i didn't expect that because there is a method in http protocol called HEAD witch gives you information aboute the page you want without loading it. But in your case you are looking for the head tag , not sure how to do it nor why  you need it . But anyway stackoverflow needs an answer for this question .

Comment: @YasserCHENIK HTML is not HTTP. HTML is transported through HTTP.

Comment: Somebody's already voting for closing this question. Why?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for question 2:

Try use node-fetch's `fetch(url, {size: 200})`

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#fetchurl-options

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a method in which you can get only the head element from a response, but you can load the entire HTML document and then parse the head from it even though it might not be so efficient compared to other methods. I made a basic app using axios and cheerio to get the head element from an array of urls. I hope this might help someone.

```
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

const URLs = ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191546/get-only-html-head-from-url"] 

for (let i = 0; i < URLs.length; i++) {
    axios.get(URLs[i])
    .then(html => {
        const document = html.data


        // get the start index and the end index of the head
        const startHead = document.indexOf("<head>")
        const endHead = document.indexOf("</head>") + 7

        //get the head as a string
        const head = document.slice(startHead, endHead)

        
        // load cheerio
        const $ = cheerio.load(head)

        // get the title from the head which is loaded into cheerio
        console.log($("title").html())

    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Comment: I want to load only the `<head>` of an HTML page. Seems like `fetch` could return a `ReadableStream`, and the connection itself could be "killed" with `AbortController.abort()` before full load.